# Not getting string in xml formatted form?

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to create a xml document of following format:

```
<![CDATA[<Caption xmlns="http:happy.x.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.happybus.tv/yy/happybus.xsd">
 <TemplateID>xxxxx</TemplateID>
 <CaptionOptions>
   <CaptionField>
     <Field>xxx</Field>
     <Text>xxx</Text>
   </CaptionField>
   <CaptionField>
     <Field>xxxx</Field>
     <Text>""</Text>
   </CaptionField>
 </CaptionOptions>
 </Caption>]]>
```

Here is the code that I wrote

```
XmlDocument xml2 = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement e = xml2.CreateElement("Caption");

e.InnerText ="Hello";
XmlElement template = xml2.CreateElement("TemplateID");
template.InnerText = "#TemplateID";

XmlElement captionOptions = xml2.CreateElement("CaptionOptions");
XmlElement captionField = xml2.CreateElement("CaptionField");

XmlElement fieldId = xml2.CreateElement("FieldID");
fieldId.InnerText = "#FieldID";
XmlElement textstring = xml2.CreateElement("TextString");
textstring.InnerText = "#TextString";    

captionField.AppendChild(fieldId);
captionField.AppendChild(textstring);    
captionOptions.AppendChild(captionField);

e.AppendChild(template);
e.AppendChild(captionOptions);    
xml2.AppendChild(e);    

StringWriter string_writer2 = new StringWriter();
XmlTextWriter xml_text_writer2 = new XmlTextWriter(string_writer2);
xml_text_writer2.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
xml2.WriteTo(xml_text_writer2); // xml is your XmlDocument

string formattedXml2 = string_writer2.ToString();    
Console.Write(formattedXml2);
```

I have tried a similar example with different XML doc but it clearly work, I even tried debugging but it is not getting formatted.

Comment: does one have to add the root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the `XDocument` and related classes?  I find they make manual construction of xml easier and more intuitive since the code looks very similar to the xml.  The `ToString` method seems to output the xml formatted the way you want:

```
void Main()
{
    var xDoc = new XDocument
    (
        new XElement("Parent",
            new XElement("TemplateID", "xxxxx"),
            new XElement("CaptionOptions",
                new XElement("CaptionField",
                    new XElement("Field", "xxx"),
                    new XElement("Text", "xxx")
                ),
                new XElement("CaptionField",
                    new XElement("Field", "xxxx"),
                    new XElement("Text", "")
                )
            )
        )
    );

    Console.WriteLine(xDoc.ToString());

    //To enclose the xml in a CDATA, you could use:
    var cData = new XCData(xDoc.ToString());

    Console.WriteLine(cData.ToString());
}
```

Comment: That made my life easier! Thank you.
Though I want to add Cdata as well. 

how to write it that way, if you can update your code. (I have updated mine)

Comment: @Breathing - You can create an instance of the `XCData` class to add a CDATA section.  See the updated code.